# Remove horizontal scrollbar on Shiny UI's input

Tags: css, r, shiny

This is a minimal app that reproduces my problem:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("input1", "input1", min = as.Date("2020-02-03"), max = as.Date("2020-12-30"), 
                  value = c(as.Date(Sys.Date()), as.Date("2020-12-30"))),
      hr(),
      splitLayout(checkboxGroupInput("input2", "input2", choices = c("a", "b")),
                  verticalLayout(checkboxInput("input3", "input3")))),

  mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app generated gives an horizontal scrollbar for `input3`, even when the screen size allows it to have more than enough space. Lurking on other similar questions, people recommend giving it a `css` property with `overflow:hidden`, but I can't find where to put this piece of code. Other approaches are obviously welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include custom CSS instructions at the head of the UI part.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Include custom CSS
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML('.shiny-split-layout>div {overflow: hidden;}')),
  ),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("input1", "input1", min = as.Date("2020-02-03"), max = as.Date("2020-12-30"), 
                  value = c(as.Date(Sys.Date()), as.Date("2020-12-30"))),
      hr(),
      splitLayout(checkboxGroupInput("input2", "input2", choices = c("a", "b")),
                  verticalLayout(checkboxInput("input3", "input3")))),

    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```